# Two lines showing proportion value over time (variable not time formatted)

Tags: r, ggplot2

I'm new to R and don't know where to look for this, so apologies if this is a super stupid question.

I have a data set with the following variables:

```
   month day group Y
id
1  11    29  1     0
2  11    29  0     0
3  11    29  0     1
4  11    30  1     1
5  11    30  0     1
6  12    01  1     0
7  12    01  0     0
8  12    02  1     0
9  12    02  0     1
....................
98 12    30  0     1
99 12    30  1     0
```

For this, I would like to print a plot

- with the x-axis as the time line (as composed of `month` and `day`),
- two lines, one for `group = 0` and one for `group = 1` showing
- (on the y-axis) the proportions of `Y` for the respective group on the respective day.

I assume this is straightforward but since I'm rather new, I don't know how to (i) transform the month/ date into something that (I assume it's) `ggpolt2` can interpret and (ii) plotting the proportions per group per day.

Any help is much appreciated! Many thanks! :)

Comment: Does this mean that the proportions can only have two values, .5 (with only one of 0 or 1) and 1 (with both 0 and 1)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's an answer with base functions in R. Your question implies that you need ggplot2, you can of course use it for such a plot, but base graphics will also interpret dates.

set.seed(25)

Create a reproducible data frame similar to yours:

```
 df <- data.frame(id = 1:100, 
             month = floor(runif(100, 10,12)), 
             day = floor(runif(100,1,10)),
             group = rbinom(100, 1, 0.5), 
             Y = rbinom(100, 1, 0.5))

 df
```

Create a date column, you need a year for the date, you could add an extra column or use a fixed year

```
 df$date <- as.Date(paste(df$day, df$month, "2018", sep = "-"), format = "%d-%m-%Y")
```

Calculate proportion per group and store as a new object

```
 res <- aggregate(df$Y, list(df$group,df$date), mean)
```

Set up the plotting area

```
 plot(res$Group.2, res$x, type = "n", xlab = "Date", ylab = "Proportion")
```

Plot each line

```
 with(res[res$Group.1 == 0,], lines(Group.2, x, lty = 1))
 with(res[res$Group.1 == 1,], lines(Group.2, x, lty = 3))
```

Add a legend

```
 legend("top", lty = c(1,3), legend= c("Group 0", "Group 1"), bty = "n")
```

If you want to do it in ggplot, then you can do:

```
library(ggplot2)
ggplot(res, aes(x = Group.2, y = x, color = as.factor(Group.1))) +
  geom_line()
```

Comment: I think your aggregate function, as it is, computes the mean, but not the proportion

Comment: If the data are 1 and 0s, like in the question, then it's the same - and neater!

Comment: no, still doesn't work. Example for 1 day : group1 : Y = 0. group0 : Y = 0, 1. For this day group0 has 100% of Y (1 over 1), when your mean calculate 0.5 ( (0+1)/2 ). Or I didn't get the question right

Answer (score 0):

Here the idea is to use data table to do the calculation.
First thing is to set the Date format (I choose here posixct)

```
library(data.table)
library(ggplot2)
plouf <- setDT(plouf)
plouf[,Date := as.Date(paste0(month," ",day),format = "%m %d")]
```

after I create a column that is the sum of Y per day, just because it is convenient to calculate proportion after

```
plouf[,sumy := sum(Y), by = Date]
```

Then after I calculate the proportion per group

```
plouf[group == 1, ratio := ifelse(sumy != 0, sum(Y)/sumy,0), by = Date]
plouf[group == 0, ratio := ifelse(sumy != 0, sum(Y)/sumy,0), by = Date]
```

Here is the result of gplot

```
ggplot(data = plouf, aes(Date,ratio,color = as.factor(group) )) +
  geom_line()
```

[image]

the data

```
plouf <- read.table(text ="
id month day group Y 
1  11    29  1     0
2  11    29  0     0
3  11    29  0     1
4  11    30  1     1
5  11    30  0     1
6  12    01  1     0
7  12    01  0     0
8  12    02  1     0
9  12    02  0     1", header = T)
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like this?

```
df <- data.frame(id = 1:200, 
                 month = sample(10:12, 200, replace = T), 
                 day = sample(1:30, 200, replace = T),
                 group = rbinom(200, 1, 0.5), 
                 Y = rbinom(200, 1, 0.5))

df <- df %>%
  mutate(Date = as.POSIXct(paste(month, day), format = "%m %d")) %>%
  arrange(Date)

df %>% group_by(Date, group) %>%
  summarise(n = length(unique(Y))) %>%
  mutate(pct = n / 2) %>%
  ggplot(aes(Date, pct, group = group, color = as.factor(group))) + 
  geom_line()
```